Getting the colors of elements using Selenium Web Driver
I have an element whose border is one color and its fill is another. I want to get the color of both.
I tried "color" and "border-color" arguments in getCssValue(). However, I get only the border color.
How do I get them?

getCssValue() only returns the value of a single CSS response. You may need invoke that twice to get that data
Example Java Code Part:
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("whatever you want"));

            String backgroundColor = element.getCssValue("background-color");
            String borderColor = element.getCssValue("border-color");

            System.out.println("Bg Color: " + backgroundColor);
            System.out.println("Border Color: " + borderColor);

As another approach; you may use XPath if you are familiar with them.
